# Difference between Entity Type Standard and Managed in Common Data Service?

Tags: dynamics-crm, entities, powerapps, cds

In PowerApps entity list page, we have default five fields **Entity, Name, Type, Customizable** & **Tags**

What does the Type field mean, I couldn't find any article related to this! Even Microsoft docs is a no go!!
I do know that **Custom** is the Type assigned to the tables created by us, whereas the default tables are grouped into two - Managed & Standard [(refer screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2HXO.png).

But under what criteria do they get separated into the two groups?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This `Standard` type is part of [Common Data Model (CDM) and PowerApps nomenclature](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-powerapps-common-data-model/):

> CDM provides standard entities common across most industry domains – Sales, Purchase, Customer Service, Productivity among others. Leveraging the years of experience with Dynamics business applications and Office 365 and working with thousands of enterprise customers we have defined and implemented these standard entities that will connect to Microsoft’s first party business applications and support a broad ecosystem of ISV and customer solution development.

[Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/common-data-model/) about CDM.

`Managed` is something like First party integration apps like LinkedIn, AI, Teams, etc. You will see publish prefix like `msdyn_`, `li_`, etc to see some identities. (maybe some third party Managed entities will follow this route, I'm not sure though).

I see some ADX portal like legacy entities marked as `Standard` rather than `Managed`, and some vice versa. I would say some sausage is being made, too early to look into that & that why documentation is missing.